# Why does .to_sql() return a -1 or 1 after appending to table?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have the following set up

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
server = 'server'
database = 'database'
driver = 'driver'
database_con = f'mssql://@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}'

engine = create_engine(database_con, fast_executemany=True)
con = engine.connect()

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3]})
df.to_sql(name = 'tableName',con=con,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

after appending the table, I notice a return of either `1` or `-1`.

The documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html states it should return the number of rows impacted or none, but it is always `+-1`

Does anyone know what these mean?

Comment: Are you sure that the actual data you are inserting into the table is `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3]})`?

Comment: it is actually abt 50 columns, and all column types are either int or string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a known behaviour of pyodbc, discussed here

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/481

For a DataFrame with multiple rows, SQLAlchemy calls `.executemany()`, and pyodbc returns -1 as the `.rowcount()` for an `.executemany()` call.

For a DataFrame with a single row, SQLAlchemy calls `.execute()` and pyodbc returns 1 for the `.rowcount()` as expected (assuming that no error occurred).

Comment: thanks
Do you know if there is a way to suppress the `+-1` output?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to suppress it, but you can just ignore it.